# Is there an extended LayoutManager framework?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How to extend RecyclerView.LayoutManager？

Is there an extended LayoutManager framework?

I want to achieve the following effect with android, please see the picture

[image]

I want to know how to customize

Comment: You are asking for a Lot . on other hand there are few custom layout managers available . the one you want is `FlexboxlayoutManager` . Search it and use it ..

Comment: Thanks for your help, just getting started on stackoverflow, why is it received, Closed. This question needs to be more focused. It is not currently accepting answers., what does it mean

Comment: Please go through [off-topics](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) . your question is too broad to answer(Because u are asking us how to create a custom Layout manger which is not that easy) and you did not make any code effort . Attaching an image of expected output without any code effort is discouraged here.  i hope i answered your query . and u also got the answer for your question i.e `FlexBoxLayoutManager`.

Comment: Thank you, FlexboxlayoutManager solved my problem, mainly expressed on that picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1-FlexboxLayout- https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

Option 2-Chip/ChipGroup using random function.

```
Chip chip = findViewById(R.id.chip);
Random rnd = new Random();
int color = Color.rgb(rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
chip.setChipBackgroundColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(color));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, just getting started on stackoverflow, why is it received, Closed. This question needs to be more focused. It is not currently accepting answers., what does it mean